# Ruby: Multiply all elements of an array

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have an array A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

how can I multiply all elements with ruby and get the result? 1*2*3*4*5 = 120

and what if there is an element 0 ? How can I ignore this element?

Comment: edited to reflect that this is standard ruby, not rails specific.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is the textbook case for [inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) (also called `reduce`)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(:*)
```

As suggested below, to avoid a zero,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reject(&:zero?).inject(:*)
```

Comment: What if there is an element 0 ? How can I ignore this element?

Comment: `[array].reject(&:zero?).inject(:*)` perhaps

Comment: `inject(1, :*)` would avoid a `nil` result in case of an empty array.

Comment: although one could argue that 1 is an incorrect answer for an empty array... ;)

Comment: What if there is a `nil` element ? How to ignore `nil` elements?

Comment: use `nil?`  instead of or in addition to the `zero?` rejection

Comment: Good to mention `reduce()` as well. Semantically, that also clarifies the end result better than `inject()`: the _reduction_ of an array of values into one value.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another way to calculate this factorial!
Should you want to, you can define whatever your last number is as n.

In this case, **n=5**.

From there, it would go something like this:

```
(1..num).inject(:*)
```

This will give you **120**. Also, `.reduce()` works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a dummy way but it works :)

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = 1
A.each do |i|
    if i!= 0
        result = result*i
    else
        result
    end
end
puts result
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to understand your code later on, use this: Assume A = 5, I used n instead of A

```
n = 5
n.times {|x| unless x == 0; n =  n * x; ++x; end} 
p n
```

To carry it forward, you would:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
arb = A.first
a = A.count
a.times {|x| arb = arb * A[x]; ++x}
p arb
```