# Certain mathematical equations run on arrays in Ruby return single digits when double digits expected

Tags: arrays, ruby, math

My calculator correctly subtracts and divides, but cannot correctly add or multiply correctly when there is a number that is multi-digit. Whenever I use such a number, it cuts off the last digit of the multi-digit number. For example, 12*2 becomes 2, 10*10 becomes 1, and so on.
Updated to include init method

```rb
class Sci_Calc
    def self.init
        puts "Which function of this calculator would you like to use? "
        calc_fun = gets.chomp
        case calc_fun
        when "sub"
            self.sub
        when "add"
            self.add(gets.chomp.split("").map(&:to_i))
        when "mult"
            self.mult(gets.chomp.split("").map(&:to_i))
        when div
            self.div
        end
    end
    def self.sub()
        puts "Please put the number you would like to sub from first. "
        num1 = gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "Second number: "
        num2 = gets.chomp.to_i
        num3 = num1 - num2
        puts num3
        self.init
    end
    #For now, it can only add 1 digit numbers
    def self.add(num_array)
        sum=0;
        sum=num_array.sum
        puts sum
        self.init
    end
    #code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050869/ruby-multiply-all-elements-of-an-array
    def self.mult(mult_array)
        #Take each element in the array, and add it together.
        result = 1
        mult_array.each do |i|
            #Ignores zeroes in array.
            if i!=0
                result = result*i
            else
                result
            end
        end
        puts result
    end
    def self.div
        puts "Pick the number you would like to divide from first: "
        div1 = gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "Second number, please: "
        div2 = gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "Result is: "
        div3 = div1/div2
        puts div3
    end
end
Sci_Calc.init
```

I will gladly put the rest of the code into a pastebin if needed to answer this question.

Comment: When I try `mult([12, 2])` I get 24 .... I'm not seeing the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is `mult` rather than whatever is building `mult_array`?

Comment: Hmm. It could be a problem in the control scheme, when I try to access mult from self.init.

Comment: I I checked, and it turns out @maxpleaner is right. Mu is right as well. What could be the problem?

Comment: @NathanTibbitts I think the issue is `.split("")`. Should probably be `split(" ")` right? Otherwise, if you enter say `12 2` as input, you will get `["12", " ", "2"]` - mapped to integer that's `[12, 0, 2]`. Maybe the zero is causing the problem.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
irb> '12 2'.split("")
=> ["1", "2", " ", "2"]
```

max pleanar pointed in the right direction. 
It should be `.split(" ")`

otherwise you end up working with single digits (and zeros for " ")